# MFC SDI access View from DOC

Tags: mfc

I am new to MFC SDI app. In my CMyDOC.cpp like to access the functions in CMyView.cpp. What is the best and cleanest way to do this?. As well as going opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Doc->View: If you are going to have only one view connected to the document, you can use something like:

```
CMyView* pView = NULL;
POSITION pos = GetFirstViewPosition();
if (pos != NULL)
    pView = (CMyView*) GetNextView(pos);
```

---

View->Doc:

```
CMyDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
```

Answer (score 1):

MFC recommended way is not to directly access CView from CDocument. You should reconsider your design if you have to do that because typically your view would access the document but not other way round. You should use [UpdateAllViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eys41xfw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) mechanism to let your view(s) know of change in document.

Comment: Imagine there is a tool window that can potentially operate on any opened document.  Of course one could call the document method from the tool window. But that would require including the document header file from the tool window. Sending the appropriate WM_COMMAND command using just CView::PostMessage seems more attractive. And CView can be obtained through CDocument as Edwards' post shows.